# Getting values from a form

Tags: java, selenium

I have a form with multiple line edits and select boxes. For the test case I am writing and any future possible test cases I need to be able to get the value contained in any of these.

Currently I have an enum list containing locators for all the possible elements. I also have a page object in which I have getters for all the elements where depending on the type of element it is it passes its respective locator to either a `getSelect(By locator)` or `getLineEdit(By locator)` method which then returns the value it currently contains.

What I am wondering is if there is a standard way to complete this task? If not, is the way I am currently getting the values an efficient manner?

Comment: Pretty sure that defining page classes **is** the way to go when doing robust Selenium work, so I'd say that what you're doing is just fine.

Comment: Maybe you can add a bit code sample better to see what you are doing, but according to your description it seems OK to me also this can be helpful http://zurmo.org/wiki/selenium